# Most efficient way to loop through rows of a list/database and compare values to a dictionary - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

matching_items is a database with 5 columns and 30+ rows.

Looping through each row of matching_items, I'm trying to match the 3rd column value i.e. b[2] with an entry in a dictionary (d1).

Once there is a match, another dictionary (d2) is then used to tell python which Microsoft Excel cell to change, to the first column value of that row of the database.

Is the only way to this to continue adding more 'if' statements, or is there a better way to script this? As I have many more entries in the d1 dictionary.

```
z = workbook["Spec"]
matching_items = select_all_from_db("SELECT * FROM spec_sheets where item_id LIKE '%s'" % a)
for b in matching_items:
    if b[2] == d1["name"]:
        z[d2["name_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["date"]: 
        z[d2["date_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["stage"]:
        z[d2["stage_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["prod"]:
        z[d2["prod_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["start_date"]:
        z[d2["start_date_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["end_date"]:
        z[d2["end_date_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["mixers"]:
        z[d2["mixers_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["mix_tech"]:
        z[d2["mix_tech_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["assistant"]:
        z[d2["assistant_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["assistant"]:
        z[d2["assistant_xl"]] = b[1]
    if b[2] == d1["assistant"]:
        z[d2["assistant_xl"]] = b[1]
```

Comment: "matching_items is a database with 5 columns and 30+ rows." What is a "database", exactly? What is the *type of `matching_items`*?

Comment: I'm querying a mysql database, the data returned has 5 columns and about 30 rows. i.e [(value 1a, value 1b, value 1c, value 1d, value 1e),
(value 2a, value 2b, value 2c, value 2d, value 2e),
(value 3a, value 3b, value 3c, value 3d, value 3e),
Etc...